# Are there any free alternatives to VisualSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visualsvn, ankhsvn

Are there any free alternatives to VisualSVN (a Visual Studio 2008 plugin for subversion control)? Visual Studio Express 2008 support would be great.

Comment: Update: VisualSVN 3.0 is free when used on computers that are not joined to Active Directory domain: http://www.visuaslvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I use and love [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/).  I don't think VS 2008 Express supports add-ins or packages...

Answer (score 12):

[TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/) is a fantastic free alternative that integrates tightly with Windows Explorer, but not Visual Studio specifically.

Comment: It's interesting that this is so high since the question sounds like it's specifically for a Visual Studio plugin. I suppose people love their Tortoise plugins. My only complaint is the indexing eating up resources and it not refreshing the folder/file icons always. Due to this, I prefer the command line tools. I will say that my work machine isn't less then optimal for a developer machine in the Microsoft world.

Comment: I use cygwin myself, but my co-workers use Tortoise...

Answer (score 6):

VisualSVN 3.0 is free when used on computers that are not joined to Active Directory domain:
http://www.visualsvn.com/visualsvn/purchase/

Answer (score 2):

[AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is free under the Apache 2.0 license and integrates with VS.  I am unsure about the Express edition (I us Professional), but give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the 2.X series of [AnkhSVN](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) supports it

Answer (score 0):

[ankhsvn....](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/)

donno about express edition sc integration - if it is possible that it will work. 
if MS blocked it.. use tortois throuhg file system.

Answer (score 0):

[ankhsvn](http://ankhsvn.open.collab.net/) is the only one I know of, but alas no Express support.