# Are there any free alternatives to VisualSVN or AnkhSVN?

Tags: visual-studio, svn, visual-studio-2017, visualsvn, ankhsvn

[I know it already exists this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1922816/are-there-any-free-alternatives-to-visualsvn), but since it's from 2009, I want to ask it again to know if there is any good other alternative.

In the question I referenced before, they mention:

- **AnkhSVN:** Not working in the latest Visual Studio 2017 versions.
- **TortoiseSVN:** Not integrated with Visual Studio.

Also, I am in an Active Directory domain, so the free license is inapplicable to me.

Comment: AnkhSVN works perfectly with VS 2017. I've been using it for years. What problems do you have with it in VS 2017?

Comment: It does not work if I try to
`File > Subversion > Add solution to subversion > insert the repository Url > Ok`
It freezes there and it does not work anymore. It happens the same on three others PC's from my working partners.

We've also read on the latest comments that it does not work in the latest versions of Visual Studio 2017 (using 15.7.4).

Comment: Maybe that's just this operation that doesn't work. You can try to add the solution to subversion with TosrtoiseSVN. I'm also using VS 15.7.4 and AnkhSVN on a daily basis without any problems.

Comment: Hello, maybe you could be interested but this question I posted on Software Recommandation : https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/50424/subversion-svn-plugin-for-microsoft-visual-studio

Answer (score 2):

Looks like someone took over the old code and got it working with 2019! 
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=PhilJollans.AnkhSVN2019&ssr=false#overview

Comment: It doesn't appear to work with the "Pending Changes Filter" though.

Comment: @bpeikes Yeah I noticed that after I tried it. It seems to have other issues too. Looks like I have to finally switch to git.

Answer (score 0):

If your environment does not allow using the free VisualSVN Community license, and you don't have a paid license, you can try [integrating TortoiseSVN into Visual Studio manually](https://tortoisesvn.net/visualstudio.html). Note that this manual setup enables only a very basic integration because it only adds SVN commands to the menus. VisualSVN and AnkhSVN plug-ins offer much deeper and complete integration of SVN into Visual Studio.

BTW, it is surprising to find out that AnkhSVN does not work reliably with Visual Studio 2017. However, it seems that it's true that there are some issues and VS2017 may crash when working with AnkhSVN. There are other reports about similar behavior on Visual Studio Marketplace: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vs-publisher-303797.AnkhSVN-SubversionSupportforVisualStudio#review-details. You may want to report this to AnkhSVN developers.